# how to update the "href" from ajax response in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to update the `href` element depend upon Ajax response and need to trigger click event from the appended `href`

I am doing in the following way. But not able to trigger click event from the updated `href`.

**HTML**

```
<a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1" target="contentFrame">Audit</a>
```

**ExtJs**

```
listeners: {
      click: { 
          fn: function(node,event){
                    Ext.Ajax.request({           
                      url: '/ms/module/external-a/api/'+treeId+'/fetch-child/'+UUID,
                      method: 'GET',
                      success:  function (response) { 
                        var addInfoRes = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);                   
                        var additionalInfohref = addInfoRes.href                // "/member/erp/config?node=12";  
                        jQuery("#123").attr('href',additionalInfohref);
                      }
                    });
            }         
        },stopEvent: true

}
```

Comment: Why type of component are you using to generate the <a> tags in question. Are they buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All the **id 123** is not defined in `<a>` tag.

```
<a hidefocus="on" id="123" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1" target="contentFrame">Audit</a>
```

Secondly to trigger click we need to use the function `click()` on the selected element.

```
jQuery("#123").click();
```